# Custom MKAnnotation disappears when I alter it's coordinate

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

I don't exactly know if this has been answered before, but I have not been able to find it so I thought I would post a question.

I have a custom MKAnnotation that shows up perfectly fine if i use coordinates such as : "74.8044595495237 -21.7716836352598"

```
var currLat: Double! = 74.8044595495237
var currLong: Double! = -21.7716836352598
let egg: EggPin = EggPin(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currLat, currLong), title: "Egg", subtitle: "This is an egg")
```

That works just fine. The custom MKAnnotation shows up on the map and everything is fine and dandy. But, when I change the coordinates of the EggPin by subtracting 1.0 from currLat  and currLong like so:

```
var currLat: Double! = 74.8044595495237
var currLong: Double! = -21.7716836352598
let egg: EggPin = EggPin(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currLat - 1.0, currLong - 1.0), title: "Egg", subtitle: "This is an egg")
```

The MKAnnotation disappears. I am new to  MapKit so I feel like I must be missing something very simple about setting coordinates. Below is my EggPin Class if that will help :

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class EggPin: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String, subtitle: String) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle

        super.init()

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the MKAnnoation went way off the screen when I subtracted 1.0 from it, but subtracting .005 worked fine as it was shown by the pin.